# How to view the model result in shiny?

Tags: r, modeling, shiny

I want to develop generalised regression model which would allow user to select the variables of their choice and see the result. I do not seem to see the result.

```
    library(shiny)
     library(dplyr)
     library(caret)
     data(mtcars)

     UI <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("MTCARS"),
  selectInput("response","y",
              names(mtcars)),
  selectInput("Columns","Columns",
              names(mtcars), multiple = TRUE),
  actionButton('btn_train',label = 'Calibrate Model',
               icon = icon('cogs'),#'bullseye','rocket'
               class='btn-danger fa-lg',
               width='100%'),
  dataTableOutput("dfStr")


)

Server <- function(input, output) {

  x <- reactive({as.character(input$Columns)})
  y <- reactive({as.character(input$response)})
 framework <- reactive({train(reformulate(x(), y()), data = mtcars, method='glm', maxit=500, trace=F)})
 modeloutput <- reactive({
   summary(framework()) 
 })

 observeEvent(input$btn_train,
              output$dfStr <- renderPrint({
                str(modeloutput())
              }))
}

shinyApp(UI, Server)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is that you are using `dataTableOutput("dfStr")` instead of  `verbatimTextOutput("dfStr")`.

Also the the `Calibrate Model` button is doing nothing since you are using reactive variables to build the model.

Comment: Hey Geovany, Thank you for your advice. One problem that I am now having is that instead of getting model result summary like coefficient and Rsquare values. It is giving me a lot of unwanted text. If you may run the code at your end, you will see the problem. Thank you again

Comment: If you want to use dataTableOutput in ui side, you must use matching render function. So it's either verbatimTextOutput for the ui part or renderDataTable for the server part. Next, it's better to specify want kind of table output you want at the end, because summary results won't be in desired fashion. You can get necessary information from your framework() value, like framework()$ (use str() to find the structure of your output). If you want simple output, just use verbatimTextOutput  in ui and call only framework() in server part

Comment: Thank you for your help Asayat. I used two methods that you suggested. Unfortunately, none of them give me the summary output of my model. May be I am reading your comments correctly. Would you please post your code as a comment. The code is reproducible because I am using data that already exists in R.

Comment: Check out what R gives your for summary(framework). It's not a data.frame. If you want to show the results as table, then specify what kind of table you want. You can't put list object to render a table.